# Why do all the Linux ISOs I try to download seem to fail mid-transfer lately?

Tags: download, file-transfer, http, data-transfer, file-download

I've sat here for hours upon hours, repeatedly trying to download the ISO for Linux Mint from numerous of its mirrors. Servers from all over the world. They all stop halfways (not *literally* exactly halfways, to be clear) with a generic "failed" message (Pale Moon). It's like they cut off the connection after a certain time.

Has the entire Internet broken down completely? Is somebody trying to prevent me from installing Linux? I can't even download files anymore? I have no idea how I'm supposed to do anything when nothing works. It's not even an exaggeration anymore.

I never had such issues in the past, even downloading much bigger files, many years ago. But now...?

I could understand if I'm banned or something, but then the file transfer wouldn't start to begin with. Why is it cut off in the middle or after a certain amount of time? What's the point of that?

And it's fast while it's working, too: 1 MB/s. (yes: mega**byte**.) So it's not like it's "timing me out" for being too slow or something.

Answer (score 2):

No, the Internet has not broken down completely.  It is conceivable but very unlikely that your ISP or a similar middleman between you and the site has trying to cut off your connection.   (Also, 1 megabyte per second is not fast in the developed world.  I live rurally on an island in the South Pacific and get a connection of 2-4 times that on a slower-then-average-because-its-rural home user connection).

Thinking more on this, its conceivable that you are behind Carrier Grade NAT, and for whatever reason the connection tracking is breaking and you are loosing your connection mid-way through.

There are a few things which may or may not be useful to you -

1. Ensure you have plenty of free disk space.
2. Try an alternative browser.
3. Try ditching the browser and getting the ISO via bittorrent.  This has the advantage of resuming if there is an error / disconnection)
4. If possible, connect over ethernet rather then WIFI.   Its unlikely, but it is possible for others to send "de-auth" packets to break your WIFI connection. Maybe you are using all the available shared bandwidth and pissing someone off.
5. A (UDP based ideally, eg one using OpenVPN UDP protocol) VPN would likely bypass issues/roadblocks thrown up by carrier grade nat or your ISP - although this would require a VPN.

Comment: +1 for trying BitTorrent. This seems like the next logical step if OP has a poor connection.

Comment: I'd add a 6. to that list - use a download manager. ISPs will try to cache web downloads invisibly, which can crap out, as you've discovered. Once it has, any re-try will fetch the same crapped-out version, ad nauseam. A download manager will segment the file so your ISP doesn't try to cache the whole thing. They're almost all resumable too, in case the connection does drop. …and, yeah, 1MB/s is not much these days. I get 25 or so & I'm not even on the fastest available speeds here.

Comment: @tetsujin fair enough, although nowadays I don't think ISP caching us a thing because it breaks https.

Comment: tbh, I've used DL managers so long I'd just never think to work without one. I suppose it's more habit than working to current 'spec' but it never fails.